# ScrollPane scroll does not work with other nodes

Tags: java, javafx

I want to have StackPane as my root pane. I want to have a scrollPane as a small box in the middle of the scene and two buttons **below** the container.

I tried to make it happen by writing this code:

```java
 private StackPane root = new StackPane();
    private Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1366, 768);

    public ContinueScreen() {
        Button button1 = new ButtonBuilder("My Button1").setPrefWidth(200).build();
        Button button2 = new ButtonBuilder("My Button2").setPrefWidth(200).build();
        Button button3 = new ButtonBuilder("My Button3").setPrefWidth(200).build();
        Button button4 = new ButtonBuilder("My Button4").setPrefWidth(200).build();
        Button button5 = new ButtonBuilder("My Button5").setPrefWidth(200).build();
        Button button6 = new ButtonBuilder("My Button6").setPrefWidth(200).build();

        VBox vBox = new VBox(5);
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6);

        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setContent(vBox);
        scrollPane.setPannable(true);
        scrollPane.setMaxSize(500, 180);
        scrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);

        root.getChildren().add(scrollPane);
        StackPane.setAlignment(scrollPane, Pos.CENTER);

    }
```

As you can probably notice, the code does work perfectly fine but that is until I add the buttons below I was talking about. I added those buttons in an HBox as

```java
        HBox hBox = new HBox(5);
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(new Button("cat"), new Button("dog"));
        root.getChildren().addAll(hBox);
```

Now both the scrollpane and the two buttons are shown. However the scroll pane now stops working for some reason. The scrollpane is shown and its content but the horizontal or the vertical scroll, both of them do not work. Anyone knows why is this happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using StackPane as root it piles up the nodes on one another so the top pane is HBox and not the ScrollPane, so it you are not able to use.

Use BorderPane or VBox and try.

```
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1366, 768);
        root.setCenter(scrollPane);
        HBox hBox = new HBox(5);
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(new Button("cat"), new Button("dog"));
        root.setBottom(hBox);
```

Comment: Thanks but I have a problem. When I use the BorderPane as a root, I am not able to  center it to the position I am talking about. Which is just below the scroll pane. I referred to some other questions but that did not help. Here is my code: https://pastebin.com/DmPqur0B

Comment: Have you tried setting `hBox.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);`

Comment: It does not seem to work as well. It only moves slightly above but is still aligned at the bottom left of the scene.

Comment: @user3845934 Not `BorderPane.setAlignment` you need to use `hBox.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);`

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that `StackPane` is allowed to resize the `HBox`, which it does. The `HBox` covers the complete scene preventing mouse events from reaching the `ScrollPane`. You can easily see this by coloring the `HBox`:

```
hBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(100%, 0%, 0%, 0.5)");
```

The most simple solution would be to set up the `HBox` to only receive events on non-(fully-)transparent areas:

```
hBox.setPickOnBounds(false);
```

However you could also set up the `HBox` to take up the space required to fit the preferred size of the content and do the alignment via the `StackPane`:

```
hBox.setPrefSize(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
hBox.setMaxSize(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE, Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
StackPane.setAlignment(hBox, Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
// hBox.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
```

Note that using a `StackPane` like this does not provide you with a responsive GUI: If you resize the window to a small enough height, the buttons will cover the `ScrollPane`.

You may have better luck using a `BorderPane` or wrapping the `StackPane` and the `HBox` in a `VBox` and setting `VBox.vgrow` to `Priority.ALWAYS` for the `StackPane`...